# How to plot correctly the stream and potential lines of a Uniform flow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was messing around with the plots of the potential flow theory, but there was a problem with the results, the streamlines were being plot like the equipotential lines, and viceversa.

For this case, I used just a uniform flow with a velocity of 10 m/s in the positive x-direction, so the streamlines should be blue-shaded lines parallel to the x-axis, and red-shaded equipotential lines parallel to the y-direction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

#--- Constants ---#
nx = 5                         # nx: number of time steps in 'x'
ny = 5                         # ny: number of time steps in 'y'
dx = 1 
dy = 0.5 
U = 10.0

lower_x = 0.0
lower_y = 0.0

#-----------------#

XY = []

phi  = np.zeros((nx, ny))       # potential function    matrix
psi  = np.zeros((nx, ny))       # stream    function    matrix

for j in range(0, ny):
    for i in range(0, nx):
        xi = i * dx + lower_x
        yi = j * dy + lower_y
        XY.append((xi, yi))
        #--  potential function  --#        
        phi[i][j] = U * xi 
        #--  stream function  --#
        psi[i][j] = U * yi

print("XY = ", XY, "\n\n")
print("Psi = ", psi)

#--- plotting part ---#
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, nx)   
y = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#cs = ax.contour(X, Y, phi, cmap=cm.hot)
#ax.clabel(cs, inline = 1, fontsize = 10)

cs_1 = ax.contour(X, Y, psi, cmap=cm.Blues)
ax.clabel(cs_1, inline = 1, fontsize = 10)

plt.show()
```

So I wanted to have the streamlines parallel to the x-axis, but the script needs to change something in the plotting part in order to show a proper plot, how can I get the proper plot instead of something rotated?

Comment: I suppose simply swapping X and Y arguments is not a solution?

Comment: Well, yeah, it's kinda true, even though it doesn't seem right. Anyway, it works , and that should do the trick for now :)